# @tanstack/react-table library Cannot read properties of null reading useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, android-activity, tanstack

> Blockquote

I used vite to boostrap my react app with ("@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.2") for my table. Locally everything works fine but can't say thesame for production as it throws a blank screen.

```
The following error occurs in production.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at e.useState (chunk-ASRYAZ7L.js:290:24)
    at OJ (@tanstack_react-table.js:3349:28)
    at j$e (PartListTable.tsx:96:17)
    at wC (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:4050:11)
    at H3 (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:7186:15)
    at B3 (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:6853:15)
    at Eee (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:6846:9)
    at my (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:6829:11)
    at GC (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:6545:11)
    at M3 (chunk-BMTCLU35.js:6606:32)
 

vite.connfig.ts:
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { defineConfig, UserConfig } from "vite";
import { InlineConfig } from "vitest";

type Config = UserConfig & {
  test: InlineConfig;
};

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
const config:Config = {
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: ['src/setupTest.ts'],
    mockReset: true,
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
    sourcemap: true,
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [],
    },
     rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "react",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
          "react/jsx-runtime": "react/jsx-runtime",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    disabled: false,
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
    open: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser",
    },
  },
};

export default defineConfig(config)


tsConfig file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/redux/hooks/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@customredux/*": ["src/redux/*"],
      "@customtypes/*": ["src/types/*"]
    },
   /* Linting */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "./setupTest.ts", "vite.config.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]

}

Package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "update": "git pull origin develop",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "build:docker": "docker system prune -f && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build",
    "preview": "vite preview --host",
    "test:clear": "vitest --clearCache",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=text-summary --reporter=html --include='src/**' --all vitest run --coverage",
    "test:coverage": "nyc --reporter=text-summary --reporter=html --include='src/**' --all vitest run --coverage && nyc check-coverage --statements 70 --branches 70 --functions 70 --lines 70",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.jsx,.tsx --fix",
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "release": "standard-version"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.3.9",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.5.2",
    "@choc-ui/chakra-autocomplete": "^5.1.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/system": "^5.13.2",
    "@orama/orama": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.4.3",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/react-lottie": "^1.2.6",
    "async-mutex": "^0.4.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^10.8.5",
    "i18next": "^22.4.13",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "yup": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.4.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.4.4",
    "@commitlint/types": "^17.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.56.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.56.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.1",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.31.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "commitlint": "^17.4.4",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-cli": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^10.8.5",
    "happy-dom": "^9.20.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "i18next": "^22.4.13",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "standard-version": "^9.5.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vitest": "^0.31.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "=16.x"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
}
```

Been on this for more than 5 hours surfing the internet and implementing suggested solutions like changing the project config, adding a rollupOptions and more but that seems not to be a fix for this issue or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Will gladly appreciate a helping hand.

--  Solved  ----

Am back with a fix for this issue.

Seems this issue has something to do with the project setup. I figured that for some reason the useReactTable hook is unable to access the useState hook hence the error during initialization.

I had to create a similar implementation of the hook manually and then use the custom manual hook I created instead of the one offered by the library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).